# Is there any way of chaining too many document.getElementById on a particular id of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, css

```
function showShape(){
  var top=Math.random()*370;
  var left=Math.random()*350;
  var width=Math.random()*300;
  var height=Math.random()*300;
  start = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.top=top + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.left=left + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.width=width+"px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.height=height+"px";
}
```

I want to reduce the redundancy.There is too many documentgetelement that I want to get rid of.

Comment: Call it once and store the return value in a variable.

Comment: put it in a var: `var shape = document.getElementById("shape"); shape.style...`

Comment: Just FYI, `document.getElementById("shape").style = "display: block; top: 5px; …"` would also work to set all these styles in one go, you’d just have to assemble them in one string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Cache your element

2) Create an randomise function that accepts a number and returns an integer.

3) Ensure your element has its [position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) set.

```js
const shape = document.getElementById('shape');

function rnd(seed) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * seed);
}

function showShape(shape) {
  var top = rnd(370);
  var left = rnd(350);
  var width = rnd(300);
  var height = rnd(300);
  shape.style.position = 'absolute';
  shape.style.display = 'block';
  shape.style.top = `${top}px`;
  shape.style.left = `${left}px`;
  shape.style.width = `${width}px`;
  shape.style.height = `${height}px`;
}

showShape(shape);
```

```css
#shape {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape" />
```

Further documentation:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

It's called caching. Not only you will write less code, but also greatly improve performance.

```
const shapeElem = document.getElementById("shape");

function showShape(){
  var top=Math.random()*370;
  var left=Math.random()*350;
  var width=Math.random()*300;
  var height=Math.random()*300;
  start = new Date().getTime();
  shapeElem.style.display = "block";
  shapeElem.style.top=top + "px";
  shapeElem.style.left=left + "px";
  shapeElem.style.width=width+"px";
  shapeElem.style.height=height+"px";
}
```